# Spring Batch & My Batis: MyBatisBatchItemWriter throws IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I'm using Spring Batch with MyBatis to write file data into a MySql database using the MyBatisBatchItemWriter.

Here are the configuration & code implementation:

**Batch Configuration:**

```
@Autowired
private SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory;

@Bean
public Job userPostJob() throws IOException {
  log.info("Begin userPostJob Job");
  return jobBuilderFactory.get("userPostJob")
      .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).listener(userPostJobCompletionNotificationListener)
      .flow(userPostFlow())
      .end()
      .build();
  }

  private Step userPostFlow() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("userWriterFlow").<UserTable, UserTable>chunk(2)
        .reader(getUserReader(null))
        .processor(userProcessor)
        .writer(myBatisUserBatchWriter())
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  @StepScope
  public FlatFileItemReader<UserTable> getUserReader(
      @Qualifier("userFileTokenizer") LineTokenizer userFileTokenizer) {

        return reader("/Users/aditya.singh/user.csv", true,
        sagawaFileTokenizer, UserTable.class);
  }



private <T> FlatFileItemReader<T> reader(String filePath, boolean skipHeaderLine,
    LineTokenizer lineTokenizer, Class<T> clazz) {
    FlatFileItemReader<T> flatFileItemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    flatFileItemReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(filePath));
    flatFileItemReader.setLinesToSkip(skipHeaderLine ? 1 : 0);

    DefaultLineMapper<T> defaultLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
    defaultLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
    defaultLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(createFieldMapper(clazz));

    flatFileItemReader.setLineMapper(defaultLineMapper);
    return flatFileItemReader;
  }

  private <T> FieldSetMapper<T> createFieldMapper(Class<T> clazz) {
    BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<T> beanWrapperFieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
    beanWrapperFieldSetMapper.setTargetType(clazz);
    return beanWrapperFieldSetMapper;
  }



public MyBatisBatchItemWriter<User> myBatisUserBatchWriter() {
    MyBatisBatchItemWriter<UserTable> cvsInfoWriter = new MyBatisBatchItemWriter();
    cvsInfoWriter.setSqlSessionFactory(sqlSessionFactory);
    cvsInfoWriter
        .setStatementId("com.batch.mapper.UserTableMapper.insert");
    return cvsInfoWriter;
  }
```

**Data Source Configuration:**

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "database")
@Setter
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

  private String driverClass;
  private String databaseUrl;
  private String username;
  private String password;
  private Integer maxPoolSize;

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    config.setDriverClassName(driverClass);
    config.setJdbcUrl(databaseUrl);
    config.setUsername(username);
    config.setPassword(password);
    config.setMaximumPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
    return new HikariDataSource(config);
  }

  @Bean
  public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
    SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
    sqlSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    return sqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject();
  }

  @Bean
  public DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager() {
    DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
    dataSourceTransactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
    return dataSourceTransactionManager;
  }

}
```

MyBatis Configurations & Generated Mapper interfaces:

1. **generatorConfig.xml**

   ```
   <commentGenerator>
     <property name="suppressDate" value="true"/>
   </commentGenerator>

   <jdbcConnection driverClass="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
     connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee"
     userId="root"
     password="root">
   </jdbcConnection>

   <javaTypeResolver>
     <property name="forceBigDecimals" value="false"/>
   </javaTypeResolver>

   <javaModelGenerator targetPackage="com.batch.model"
     targetProject="src/main/java">
     <property name="enablesubpackages" value="true"/>
     <property name="trimstrings" value="true"/>
   </javaModelGenerator>

   <javaClientGenerator type="XMLMAPPER" targetPackage="com.batch.mapper"
     targetProject="src/main/java">
     <property name="enableSubPackages" value="true"/>
   </javaClientGenerator>


   <table tableName="USER_TABLE">
     <property name="useActualColumnNames" value="false"/>
   </table>
   ```
2. **Generated Mapper class:**

```
    @ToString
    public class UserTable {

      @Generated(value = "org.mybatis.generator.api.MyBatisGenerator", comments = "Source field: USER_TABLE.id")
      private String id;

      @Generated(value = "org.mybatis.generator.api.MyBatisGenerator", comments = "Source field: USER_TABLE.name")
      private String name;

      @Generated(value = "org.mybatis.generator.api.MyBatisGenerator", comments = "Source field: USER_TABLE.id")
      public String getId() {
        return id;
      }

      @Generated(value = "org.mybatis.generator.api.MyBatisGenerator", comments = "Source field: USER_TABLE.id")
      public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
      }

      @Generated(value = "org.mybatis.generator.api.MyBatisGenerator", comments = "Source field: USER_TABLE.name")
      public String getName() {
        return name;
      }

      @Generated(value = "org.mybatis.generator.api.MyBatisGenerator", comments = "Source field: USER_TABLE.name")
      public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
      }
    }
```

3. **Generated Mapper Interface:**

```
    @Mapper
    public interface UserTableMapper {

        @Generated(value="org.mybatis.generator.api.MyBatisGenerator", comments="Source Table: USER_TABLE")
        @InsertProvider(type=SqlProviderAdapter.class, method="insert")
        int insert(InsertStatementProvider<UserTable> insertStatement);

        @Generated(value="org.mybatis.generator.api.MyBatisGenerator", comments="Source Table: USER_TABLE")
        default int insert(UserTable record) {
            return insert(SqlBuilder.insert(record)
                    .into(userTable)
                    .map(id).toProperty("id")
                    .map(name).toProperty("name")
                    .build()
                    .render(RenderingStrategy.MYBATIS3));
        }

        @Generated(value="org.mybatis.generator.api.MyBatisGenerator", comments="Source Table: USER_TABLE")
        default int insertSelective(UserTable record) {
            return insert(SqlBuilder.insert(record)
                    .into(userTable)
                    .map(id).toPropertyWhenPresent("id", record::getId)
                    .map(name).toPropertyWhenPresent("name", record::getName)
                    .build()
                    .render(RenderingStrategy.MYBATIS3));
        }

         // Other update & select methods
    }
```

4. **User Table Dynamic Sql Support class:**

```
public final class UserTableDynamicSqlSupport {

    @Generated(value="org.mybatis.generator.api.MyBatisGenerator", comments="Source Table: USER_TABLE)
    public static final UserTable userTable = new UserTable();

    @Generated(value="org.mybatis.generator.api.MyBatisGenerator", comments="Source field: USER_TABLE.id")
    public static final SqlColumn<String> id = userTable.id;

    @Generated(value="org.mybatis.generator.api.MyBatisGenerator", comments="Source field: USER_TABLE.name")
    public static final SqlColumn<String> name = userTable.name;

    @Generated(value="org.mybatis.generator.api.MyBatisGenerator", comments="Source Table: USER_TABLE")
    public static final class UserTable extends SqlTable {
        public final SqlColumn<String> id = column("id", JDBCType.VARCHAR);

        public final SqlColumn<String> name = column("name", JDBCType.VARCHAR);

        public UserTable() {
            super("USER_TABLE");
        }
    }
}
```

**Exception Stack Trace:**

```
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error invoking SqlProvider method 'public java.lang.String org.mybatis.dynamic.sql.util.SqlProviderAdapter.insert(org.mybatis.dynamic.sql.insert.render.InsertStatementProvider)' with specify parameter 'class com.batch.model.UserTable'.  Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:78)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:440)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65.update(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.update(SqlSessionTemplate.java:287)
    at org.mybatis.spring.batch.MyBatisBatchItemWriter.write(MyBatisBatchItemWriter.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:188)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:154)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:212)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:203)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:68)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:136)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:313)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:144)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:137)
    at com.batch.controller.JobLauncherController.launchUserPostJob(JobLauncherController.java:40)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:798)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error invoking SqlProvider method 'public java.lang.String org.mybatis.dynamic.sql.util.SqlProviderAdapter.insert(org.mybatis.dynamic.sql.insert.render.InsertStatementProvider)' with specify parameter 'class com.batch.model.UserTable'.  Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.annotation.ProviderSqlSource.createSqlSource(ProviderSqlSource.java:151)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.annotation.ProviderSqlSource.getBoundSql(ProviderSqlSource.java:113)
    at org.apache.ibatis.mapping.MappedStatement.getBoundSql(MappedStatement.java:297)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.BaseStatementHandler.<init>(BaseStatementHandler.java:64)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.<init>(PreparedStatementHandler.java:41)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.<init>(RoutingStatementHandler.java:46)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.newStatementHandler(Configuration.java:592)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BatchExecutor.doUpdate(BatchExecutor.java:57)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:117)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.update(CachingExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:197)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:426)
    ... 83 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.annotation.ProviderSqlSource.invokeProviderMethod(ProviderSqlSource.java:191)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.annotation.ProviderSqlSource.createSqlSource(ProviderSqlSource.java:134)
    ... 98 common frames omitted
```

I have been debugging this till the method invocation by Java, but failing to get it resolved.

Also, ***if I use a writer class (below), it works fine and saves the data.***

```
@Component
public class UserWriter implements ItemWriter<UserTable> {

  @Autowired
  private UserTableMapper userTableMapper;

  @Override
  public void write(List<? extends UserTable> items) throws Exception {
    for (UserTable userTable : items) {
      log.info("Writing user info: {}", userTable);
      userTableMapper.insert(userTable);
    }

  }
}
```

**Versions (pom.xml):**

```
// Spring Boot 
    <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
      <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <java.version>1.8</java.version>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mybatis.dynamic-sql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mybatis-dynamic-sql</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
      <artifactId>mybatis-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

The MyBatis docs have very limited information on this, and I feel I've done the way it expects the MyBatisBatchItemWriter.

Can someone help me find issue in this small & simple piece of code?

Answer (score 3):

In current implementation, the `MyBatisBatchItemWriter` does not support calling default method on mapper interface because it call the mapper statement via `SqlSession` interface. In this case, the `MyBatisBatchItemWriter` call the mapper statement corresponding to `int insert(InsertStatementProvider<UserTable> insertStatement);` rather than `int insert(UserTable record)`. Therefore, If you want to call default method, you should create a custom item writer. As Alternative, you can use the `itemToParameterConverter` property for converting to `InsertStatementProvider<UserTable>` from `UserTable` as follow:

```
public MyBatisBatchItemWriter<UserTable> myBatisUserBatchWriter() {
  MyBatisBatchItemWriter<UserTable> cvsInfoWriter = new MyBatisBatchItemWriter<>();
  cvsInfoWriter.setSqlSessionFactory(sqlSessionFactory);
  cvsInfoWriter.setStatementId("com.batch.mapper.UserTableMapper.insert");
  cvsInfoWriter.setItemToParameterConverter(record -> SqlBuilder.insert(record)
      .into(userTable)
      .map(id).toProperty("id")
      .map(name).toProperty("name")
      .build()
      .render(RenderingStrategy.MYBATIS3));
  return cvsInfoWriter;
}
```

Comment: How would I get the "record" field? In Spring batch, the processor has to pass on the writable model.

Comment: Kizuki is correct, but had a small typo in his code - the record is available in the lamba (change "source" to "record"). I've just pushed a full example here: https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-dynamic-sql/tree/master/src/test/java/examples/springbatch/bulkinsert

Comment: I've fixed typo.